# php read file from root directory

Tags: php

I want to read file placed in the directory placed in root.
Let the file be at the place `/root/folder/file.txt`
This is my code:

I place this code in a file at `/var/www/html/test.php` that is my public html folder.

Now , when I open this file from my browser I get nothing on the screen ( that is because error reporting is off ) but when I open the same file placed in the same directory in CLI mode that is by ssh it gives me the correct output ( that is the array containing the contents of the file).

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root folder is (typically) for the root user with no read access to outside users.  Therefore, your script that is being run by the apache user won't be able to access it to read it.

Comment: even if the file mode is 777 of the file ?

Comment: The `/root` and `/root/folder` directories would also have to be executable by the web server user.  It is generally a bad idea to give such wide access to `/root`.  Maybe you should put your file somewhere else?

Comment: It inherits, so you would need to do that to `/root` and to `/root/folder`.

Comment: Which place should be perfect so a php file in /root/folder and /var/www/html/ both can access it ? /var/www/html/ ?

Comment: Assuming that you are running `/root/folder` as the root user - anywhere would be accessible for it, so `/var/www/` would work if you don't want it available from the browser specifically, or `/var/www/html` if you do.